# chrome bookmark to open another browser?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but figured I'd ask because I know other people have this problem.

I have to use an admin console for some program that is only compatible with IE.

Can I have a Chrome bookmark that when clicked on opens the URL for the admin console in a different browser (IE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not think what you are asking for is possible, you can use [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US) to open Internet Explorer inside of Chrome.  This is an excellent tool if you prefer Chrome, but still use IE bases web pages.